# How to sample() exact number of rows, not fraction, of PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to select the exact number of rows randomly from my PySpark DataFrame. I know of the function `sample()`. But it won't let me input the exact number of rows I want. The problem is when I do `sampled_df = df.sample(0.2)`, if my `df` has 1,000,000 rows, I don't necessarily get 200,000 rows in `sampled_df`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of [rand](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html) and [limit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit.html) , specifying the required `n` number of rows

```
sparkDF.orderBy(F.rand()).limit(n)
```

Note it is a simple implementation, which provides you a rough number of rows, additionally you can filter the dataset to your required conditions first , as OrderBy is a costly operation